# How to work with Oracle DB on Oracle Linux Server?

Tags: php, linux, database, server, oracleclient

I have a Oracle Linux Server. I upload there my website that written on PHP. How to install and configure Oracle DB Client on server?

The database is located on remote host, in my code I use to connect

```
$conn = oci_connect("databae_user",
                    "####",
                    "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
                                               (HOST = 10.10.10.13)
                                               (PORT = 1521)
                                    )
                                    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db_name)))", 
                     "AL32UTF8");`
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the latest PHP 7.4 and corresponding PHP OCI8 extension available from Oracle Linux yum server:

```
$ sudo yum install -y oracle-php-release-el7
$ sudo yum install -y php php-oci8-19c
```

...install Oracle Instant Client from the same yum server:

```
$ sudo yum -y install oracle-release-el7 
$ sudo yum -y install oracle-instantclient19.5-basic
```

That should do the trick.

Source: [PHP Packages for Oracle Linux](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-php.html)

Comment: A `yum-config-manager --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient` is needed/recommended after installing `oracle-release-el7 `